# Unable to access to own hosting web service from public IP

Tags: networking, router, firewall, port-forwarding, web-services

For background, I have a AspNet core webservice installed in my own server using iis.
When accessing from inside the network the service response perfectly, but when accessing from outside (using the mobile phone data or a friends computer) never responds. I installed the service on a server a friend of mine gave me for testing purposes that didn't have any type of firewall and it worked fine.

The problem is that I've already forwarded my port and disabled the firewall, but still can't access from outside to the service on my own server. I did contact my ISP to check if there were any problems, they did disable the firewall of the router, but still wasn't working. I have used https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ to see if the port is open and it is, so I think the forwarding may not be working, but the ISP told me that it has to.
Things I've done:

- Forwarding the router port to my local port.
- An inbound rule for the port of the web service.
- Disabling the firewall.
- Disabling the router firewall.
- On my iis manager I set the bindings to all IPs.
- Contacting my ISP to check for problems.

**EDIT:** I looked to the firewall logs and it shows ALLOW to the request done in private network and in outside the network so the request is passing the firewall, but when doing it outside the network I never receive the response. There is no unbound rule so that's not the problem.

Also, my web service is logging the request and even though the request is passing through the firewall it never reaches the web service since there is no log of it.

**EDIT 2:** Since my installation is similar to the installation of the following [link](https://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/creating-a-reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-for-iis) I'm trying to use a reverse proxy following the steps mentioned in the link, but is still not working.

Here is the log data of the firewall with a public request (first one) and a local request (second one):

```
#Version: 1.5
#Software: Microsoft Windows Firewall
#Time Format: Local
#Fields: date time action protocol src-ip dst-ip src-port dst-port size tcpflags tcpsyn tcpack tcpwin icmptype icmpcode info path
2019-07-16 15:50:49 ALLOW TCP 192.168.0.254 192.168.0.10 62469 5000 0 - 0 0 0 - - - RECEIVE
2019-07-16 15:52:05 ALLOW TCP 192.168.0.50 192.168.0.10 51251 5000 0 - 0 0 0 - - - RECEIVE
```

And here is the log file of my web service:

```
[2019/07/16 15:44:03.830]: (Info): Starting
[2019/07/16 15:52:07.765]: (Info): PublicController -> CheckServer
[2019/07/16 15:52:07.767]: (Info): CheckServer
```

The firewall is not blocking the request as we can see, but the request never arrives to the web service.

**EDIT 3:**
I've used Microsoft Message Analyzer and I get the following for local request:
[Analyzer of a local request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7jSI.png)

And the following for an external request:
[Analyzer of a public request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bnIN.png)

I see that it does not return the HTTP response in the public request, I don't know why any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure your ISP is not using [Carrier Grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT)?

Comment: Hi @DavidPostill I contacted my ISP and told me they don't use Carrier Grade NAT they use PAT (Port Address Translation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got it working, but I don't really have a proper solution. Today my coworkers told me that the internet stopped working a few times, probably because my ISP was doing something, so when I came back I tried to connect to the web service and it worked, I didn't make any changes, I didn't touch or do anything, but now it just works. I thought that my ISP had resolved the issue after calling them too many times, so I contacted them asking what they did and they told me that they didn't do anything (I don't know what to think...).

So in conclusion, if none of the methods I tried to solve the issue works for you just contact the ISP until they solve the issue.